# Combining files in Notepad++

Tags: file, notepad++

Is there a Notepad++ plugin out there that automatically combines all currently opened files into a single file?

**Update:** Yes, I am very aware of copy and paste :) I'm working with lots of files, and I want a solution that makes this step in the process a little bit faster than several dozen copy and pastes.

I'm aware of utilities for combining files, but I want the convenience of combining specifically the files that are currently opened in my text editor.

If there isn't a plugin out there already, I'll write one myself; I was just wondering if it exists already to save me the time of developing one.

Comment: @delnan If you're combining 20 files at a time, that can get kind of tedious...

Comment: It's propably still faster than looking for a plugin, installing it, realizing it's not working, finding another one, running it, realizing it screwed up and fixing everything by hand :D Okay, serious: If there's an existing solution, great, but there propably isn't.

Comment: if you're on Windows you don't need NP++ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418549/need-to-combine-lots-of-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I installed the [Python Script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) and wrote a simple script:

```
console.show()
console.clear()
files = notepad.getFiles()
notepad.new()
newfile = notepad.getCurrentFilename()
for i in range(len(files) - 1):
    console.write("Copying text from %s\n" % files[i][0])
    notepad.activateFile(files[i][0])
    text = editor.getText()
    notepad.activateFile(newfile)
    editor.appendText(text)
    editor.appendText("\n")
console.write("Combine Files operation complete.")
```

It looks at all the files currently opened in Notepad++ and adds them to a new file. Does exactly what I need.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work fine when there is a no saved file opened. When that happens, all files are combined in the last saved filed opened. Anyway, very useful.

Comment: Just used this in 2020. Still works great. One edit I made to the script was len(files) - 1. to just len(files). With 3 files opened it only merged the first 2. Overall, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 25):

I used the following command in DOS prompt to do the merge for me:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt
```

It is fast and it works. Just ensure that all the files to be merge are in the same directory from where  you execute this command.

Comment: just what I needed for my simple scenario, works fine with log files ending with weird formats like log.03381 or log.03455 for example, I just modified the pattern to `*.03*`

Comment: Simplest and fastest and to the point. Thanks, @Hendrik

Comment: for avoiding merging output again and again into your files, Set output.txt into another directory .

Answer (score 15):

http://www.scout-soft.com/combine/

Not my app, but this plug in lets you combine all open tabs into one file.

Comment: I've tried it today August 28, 2015 with the latest notepad++, it still works perfectly.
Thanx a lot for sharing this resource.

Comment: Wonderful.  Note, since I use the Plugins Manager, I was not able to download the plugin from the author's site and save it in the Plugins folder.  However, the Plugins Manager had no trouble finding the plugin and I was able to install it easily that way.

Comment: To use just open all the files you want to merge, and then do Plugins -> Combine -> Start.  The merged text will get popped into a new file and your focus will automatically go to the new file, which you can then save and edit.  Great solution.

Comment: Although oddly, I couldn't re-open the merged (saved) file with notepad++!  I had to open it with notepad and copy and paste into a new file.  So don't panic if that happens to you.