# Batch - Something Fails With: . was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I am trying to make a text-based game using Batch, and this part used to work but it suddenly doesn't. As soon as I press enter after typing a name, the program terminates suddenly and displays the error: `. was unexpected at this time`

I'm pretty sure this shouldn't even happen, and I know the error has to be somewhere in the following code:

`

```
    :CFGNAME
    cls & title N.A.M.E & color 0d
    echo  --------------------------------------
    echo           State your identity.
    echo  --------------------------------------
    echo.
    echo You need to specify things like your
    echo name and gender.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo Gender: %gender%
    echo.
    echo Enter a name. It may be up to sixteen
    echo characters long, and can contain any
    echo letter, and only letters. Most other
    echo glyphs will crash the game.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo -Enter a
    set /p tmpName=-     name: 
    echo %tmpName%> "data\temp\~playername.tmp"
    for %%? in ("data\temp\~playername.tmp") do ( set /A nameLength=%%~z? - 2 )
    del "data\temp\~playername.tmp"
    set ucdName=%tmpName%
    set ucdName=%ucdName:A= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:a= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:B= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:b= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:C= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:c= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:D= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:d= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:E= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:e= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:F= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:f= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:G= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:g= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:H= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:h= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:I= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:i= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:J= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:j= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:K= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:k= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:L= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:l= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:M= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:m= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:N= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:n= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:O= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:o= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:P= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:p= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:Q= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:q= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:R= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:r= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:S= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:s= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:T= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:t= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:U= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:u= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:V= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:v= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:W= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:w= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:X= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:x= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:Y= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:y= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:Z= %
    set ucdName=%ucdName:z= %
    set "ucdName=!ucdName: =!"
    echo %ucdName%x> "data\temp\~checknamecontents.tmp"
    for %%? in ("data\temp\~checknamecontents.tmp") do ( set /A invalidChars=%%~z? - 2 )
    set /a invalidChars-=1
    del "data\temp\~checknamecontents.tmp"
    if %invalidChars% gtr 0 (
        cls & title I.N.V.A.L.I.D & color 0c
        echo.
        echo Your name
        echo must only contain letters!
        echo.
        echo The name you entered cannot be
        echo used because if your name was
        echo not fully alphabetical, pass-
        echo words generated using that name
        echo would be improperly generated.
        echo It has %invalidChars%
        echo invalid character(s).
        echo.
        echo Press any key to retry...
        echo.
        pause > nul
        goto CFGNAME
    )
    :CHKNAMELENGTH
    if %nameLength% gtr 16 (
        cls & title I.N.V.A.L.I.D & color 0c
        echo.
        echo Your name must be up to 16
        echo characters in length!
        echo.
        echo The name you entered cannot be
        echo used because %nameLength% is
        echo more than 16.
        echo.
        echo.
        echo.
        echo.
        echo.
        echo Press any key to retry...
        echo.
        pause > nul
        goto CFGNAME
    ) else (
        if %nameLength% lss 3 (
            cls & title I.N.V.A.L.I.D & color 0c
            echo.
            echo Your name must be at least 3
            echo characters in length!
            echo.
            echo The name you entered cannot be
            echo used because %nameLength% is
            echo less than 3.
            echo.
            echo.
            echo.
            echo.
            echo.
            echo Press any key to retry...
            echo.
            pause > nul
            goto CFGNAME
        ) else (
            set name=%tmpName%
            goto CFGID
        )
    )
    :CFGID
    set IDEasterEgg=*
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Undyne" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Ngaaah!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Frisk" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* -_-
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Mario" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Lets-a-go!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Waluigi" (
        set IDEasterEgg=Waaa!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Link" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Nice job, "princess."
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Navi" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Hey! Listen!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Yoda" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Backwards I talk. Hm.
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Darth Vader" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* No. I am your father.
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Mabbel" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* GRAPPLING HOOK!!!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Stanley" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Illegal pyrotechnics, anyone?
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Steve" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* It's. A cow.
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Notch" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* <3
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Caillou" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* But Mommy!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Rosie" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* STUPID! STUPID! :D
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Testificate Man" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* How inconsiderate!!!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Dr Inconsiderate" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Slightly less than average!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Shaggy" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Zoinks!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Scooby-Doo" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Rello, rorld!!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Santa Claus" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Ho ho ho!
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Easter Bunny" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* You've found an Easter egg.
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Ed" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Head: Looks like flat pear.
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Edd" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Headwear: Very mysterious...
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Eddy" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Smile: Freakishly huge.
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Pacman" or "%tmpName%"=="Pac Man" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Wafers: A LOT
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Ms Pacman" or "%tmpName%"=="Ms Pac Man" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Children: Jr. Pac-Man
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Blinky" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Personality: Leader
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Clyde" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Personality: Teasing
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Inky" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Personality: Shy
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="Pinky" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* Personality: Energetic
    )
    if /i "%tmpName%"=="MatPat" (
        set IDEasterEgg=* But that's just a theory.
    )
    :CFGID
    cls & title Y.O.U S.U.R.E? & color 02
    echo  --------------------------------------
    echo        Is this ID okay with you?
    echo    ----------------------------------
    echo   This will be your character for the
    echo   rest of the game. Are you sure you
    echo     have everything exactly how you
    echo     want it? If not, you can go back
    echo     and edit your info all you like.
    echo    Anything but Y will be interpreted
    echo                as a no!
    echo  --------------------------------------
    echo.
    echo  * Name: %name%
    echo.
    echo  * Gender: %gender%
    echo.
    echo  %IDEasterEgg%
    echo.
    echo   __    __    __    __    __    __    ^|
    echo _/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/ 
    echo.
    set /p confirmCharacter=(Y, N):
```

`

If anybody can figure out what's causing the problem, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["was unexpected at this time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769591/was-unexpected-at-this-time)

Comment: Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That's far from "minimal"...

Answer (score 1):

The line `echo invalid character(s).` is the problem. The `)` closes your code block, resulting in `.` to be interpreted as a command. Escape it with a caret:

```
echo invalid character(s^).
```