# iconv any encoding to UTF-8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I am trying to point iconv to a directory and all files will be converted UTF-8 regardless of the current encoding

I am using this script but you have to specify what encoding you are going FROM. How can I make it autdetect the current encoding?

dir_iconv.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ICONVBIN='/usr/bin/iconv' # path to iconv binary

if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
  echo "$0 dir from_charset to_charset"
  exit
fi

for f in $1/*
do
  if test -f $f
  then
    echo -e "\nConverting $f"
    /bin/mv $f $f.old
    $ICONVBIN -f $2 -t $3 $f.old > $f
  else
    echo -e "\nSkipping $f - not a regular file";
  fi
done
```

terminal line

```
sudo convert/dir_iconv.sh convert/books CURRENT_ENCODING utf8
```

Comment: Related: [How to change encoding from Non-ISO extended-ASCII text?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108271/21471)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`enca`](https://github.com/nijel/enca):

> Enca is an Extremely Naive Charset Analyser. It detects character set and encoding of text files and can also convert them to other encodings using either a built-in converter or external libraries and tools like libiconv, librecode, or cstocs.
>
> Currently it supports Belarusian, Bulgarian, Croatian, Czech, Estonian, Hungarian, Latvian, Lithuanian, Polish, Russian, Slovak, Slovene, Ukrainian, Chinese, and some multibyte encodings independently on language.

Note that in general, autodetection of current encoding is a difficult process (the same byte sequence can be correct text in multiple encodings). `enca` uses heuristics based on the language you tell it to detect (to limit the number of encodings). You can use `enconv` to [convert text files](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) to a single encoding.

Comment: Your Enca link doesn't work. Is this updated one ? http://freecode.com/projects/enca

Comment: It seems like Enca moved to Github since then. Notice that the freecode site also links to nonexistent Gitorious link. Updated the link in answer.

Comment: I wonder if you meant `iconv` rather than `econv`, because I can't find `econv` in the manual.

Comment: Syntax: `enca -x utf8 -L mylanguage file.srt`.

Comment: List of valid laguages in your version: `enca -l  languages` ... But UBUNTU is **ugly** on update, my `enca --version` is 2005! How to upgrade it?

Answer (score 14):

You can get what you need using standard gnu utils file and awk. Example:

`file -bi .xsession-errors`
gives me:
"text/plain; charset=us-ascii"

so `file -bi .xsession-errors |awk -F "=" '{print $2}'`
gives me
"us-ascii"

I use it in scripts like so:

```sh
CHARSET="$(file -bi "$i"|awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"

if [ "$CHARSET" != utf-8 ]; then
  iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$i" -o outfile
fi
```

Comment: The heuristics used by `file` can be fairly crude, though. Watch out.

Comment: This method works great for Unix files in other encodings, but watch out for Microsoft Windows files which may be in UTF-16LE. This answer will convert it to UTF-8, but will leave unsightly droppings of a BOM marker at the beginning of the file and a CR at the end of each line. For files that I know are from Microsoft Windows, I've had good luck with the `dos2unix` program which handles everything: detecting the encoding, converting from UTF-16 to UTF-8, removing the BOM, and changing the line endings.

Answer (score 6):

Here is [my solution](https://gist.github.com/demofly/25f856a96c29b89baa32) to in place all files using [recode](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode/) and [uchardet](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet/):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

apt-get -y install recode uchardet > /dev/null
find "$1" -type f | while read FFN # 'dir' should be changed...
do
  encoding=$(uchardet "$FFN")
  echo "$FFN: $encoding"
  enc=`echo $encoding | sed 's#^x-mac-#mac#'`
  set +x
  recode $enc..UTF-8 "$FFN"
done
```

put it into `convert-dir-to-utf8.sh` and run:

```
bash convert-dir-to-utf8.sh /pat/to/my/trash/dir
```

Note that `sed` is a workaround for mac encodings here.
Many uncommon encodings need workarounds like this.

Comment: `uchardet` saved my script

Comment: TIP: Make a backup of your files and use a merge tool to check/compare the changes. Problems probably will appear!

Comment: `recode` doesn't seem to be maintained any more beside [this fork](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode)

Answer (score 5):

Compiling all them. Go to dir, create `dir2utf8.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# converting all files in a dir to utf8

for f in *
do
  if test -f $f then
    echo -e "\nConverting $f"
    CHARSET="$(file -bi "$f"|awk -F "=" '{print $2}')"
    if [ "$CHARSET" != utf-8 ]; then
      iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$f" -o "$f"
    fi
  else
    echo -e "\nSkipping $f - it's a regular file";
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

#### First answer

```sh
#!/bin/bash

find "<YOUR_FOLDER_PATH>" -name '*' -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' LINE_FILE; do
  CHARSET=$(uchardet $LINE_FILE)
  echo "Converting ($CHARSET) $LINE_FILE"

  # NOTE: Convert/reconvert to utf8. By Questor
  iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$LINE_FILE" -o "$LINE_FILE"

  # NOTE: Remove "BOM" if exists as it is unnecessary. By Questor
  # [Refs.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/3223785 ,
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240995/3223785 ]
  sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' "$LINE_FILE"

done
# [Refs.: https://justrocketscience.com/post/handle-encodings ,
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/3223785 ,
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659891/3223785 ]
```

**FURTHER QUESTION:** I do not know if my approach is the safest. I say this because I noticed that some files are not correctly converted (characters will be lost) or are "truncated". I suspect that this has to do with the "iconv" tool or with the charset information obtained with the "uchardet" tool. I was curious about the solution [presented by @demofly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22841847/3223785) because it could be safer.

#### Another answer

Based on @demofly 's answer:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

find "<YOUR_FOLDER_PATH>" -name '*' -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' LINE_FILE; do
  CHARSET=$(uchardet $LINE_FILE)
  REENCSED=`echo $CHARSET | sed 's#^x-mac-#mac#'`
  echo "\"$CHARSET\" \"$LINE_FILE\""

  # NOTE: Convert/reconvert to utf8. By Questor
  recode $REENCSED..UTF-8 "$LINE_FILE" 2> STDERR_OP 1> STDOUT_OP

  STDERR_OP=$(cat STDERR_OP)
  rm -f STDERR_OP
  if [ -n "$STDERR_OP" ] ; then

    # NOTE: Convert/reconvert to utf8. By Questor
    iconv -f "$CHARSET" -t utf8 "$LINE_FILE" -o "$LINE_FILE" 2> STDERR_OP 1> STDOUT_OP

    STDERR_OP=$(cat STDERR_OP)
    rm -f STDERR_OP
  fi

  # NOTE: Remove "BOM" if exists as it is unnecessary. By Questor
  # [Refs.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/3223785 ,
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240995/3223785 ]
  sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' "$LINE_FILE"

  if [ -n "$STDERR_OP" ] ; then
    echo "ERROR: \"$STDERR_OP\""
  fi
  STDOUT_OP=$(cat STDOUT_OP)
  rm -f STDOUT_OP
  if [ -n "$STDOUT_OP" ] ; then
    echo "RESULT: \"$STDOUT_OP\""
  fi
done
# [Refs.: https://justrocketscience.com/post/handle-encodings ,
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/9612232/3223785 ,
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659891/3223785 ]
```

#### Third answer

Hybrid solution with recode and vim:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

find "<YOUR_FOLDER_PATH>" -name '*' -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' LINE_FILE; do
  CHARSET=$(uchardet $LINE_FILE)
  REENCSED=`echo $CHARSET | sed 's#^x-mac-#mac#'`
  echo "\"$CHARSET\" \"$LINE_FILE\""

  # NOTE: Convert/reconvert to utf8. By Questor
  recode $REENCSED..UTF-8 "$LINE_FILE" 2> STDERR_OP 1> STDOUT_OP

  STDERR_OP=$(cat STDERR_OP)
  rm -f STDERR_OP
  if [ -n "$STDERR_OP" ] ; then

    # NOTE: Convert/reconvert to utf8. By Questor
    bash -c "</dev/tty vim -u NONE +\"set binary | set noeol | set nobomb | set encoding=utf-8 | set fileencoding=utf-8 | wq\" \"$LINE_FILE\""

  else

    # NOTE: Remove "BOM" if exists as it is unnecessary. By Questor
    # [Refs.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/3223785 ,
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240995/3223785 ]
    sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' "$LINE_FILE"

  fi
done
```

This **was the solution with the highest number of perfect conversions**. Additionally, we did not have any truncated files.

---

- **WARNING:** Make a backup of your files and use a merge tool to check/compare the changes. Problems probably will appear!
- **TIP:** The command `sed -i '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' "$LINE_FILE"` can be executed after a preliminary comparison with the merge tool after a conversion without it since it can cause "differences".
- **NOTE:** The search using `find` brings all non-binary files from the given path ("") and its subfolders.

Comment: Two minor notes:  I would replace `<YOUR_FOLDER_PATH>` with `"$1"` and let the end user pass in the folder path.  And for MacOS users, you need to run: `brew install recode uchardet gnu-sed`, and then change `sed` to `gsed` to get it to work.  And nice job removing binary files using `grep -I`.  Top marks!

Comment: Your suggestions were accepted almost completely. I didn't keep the change 'I would replace <YOUR_FOLDER_PATH> with "$1"', because I thought the previous approach is clearer for more people. Thanks! = D

Comment: You shouldn't provide to iconv same file for input and output https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output/10243#10243 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872302/why-iconv-command-output-to-the-same-file-is-truncated

Comment: I read that it is better to use inplace iconv `iconv -f UTF-32 -t UTF-8 file.csv` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets#comment62188586_64860

Answer (score 1):

use iconv and uchardet (thx farseerfc)

fish shell

```
cat your_file  | iconv -f (uchardet your_file ) -t UTF-8
```

bash shell

```sh
cat your_file  | iconv -f $(uchardet your_file ) -t UTF-8
```

if use bash script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
for fn in "$@"
do
    iconv < "$fn" -f $(uchardet "$fn") -t utf8
done
```

by @flowinglight at ubuntu group.

Answer (score 0):

Check out tools available for a data convertation in a linux cli: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch11.en.html

Also, there is a quest to find out a full list of encodings which are available in `iconv`. Just run `iconv --list` and find out that encoding names differs from names returned by `uchardet` tool (for example: x-mac-cyrillic in `uchardet` vs. mac-cyrillic in `iconv`)

Answer (score 0):

enca command doesn't work for my Simplified-Chinese text file with GB2312 encoding.

Instead, I use the following function to convert the text file for me.
You could of course re-direct the output into a file.

It requires **chardet** and **iconv** commands.

```
detection_cat () 
{
    DET_OUT=$(chardet $1);
    ENC=$(echo $DET_OUT | sed "s|^.*: \(.*\) (confid.*$|\1|");
    iconv -f $ENC $1
}
```