# How to find out the character set of a user uploaded document?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, user-input

I wrote a script that allows users to upload/import lots of users at once using a CSV-file. I'm using MySQL's load data local infile to make this working:

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $file INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY $delimiter 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
(email, name, organization);
```

But a user tried to import a document that contained the name `Günther`. This was saved to the database as "G" (cutting of the rest). The document turned out to be in `latin1` causing the problems. I don't want to bother my users with character sets and stuff.

I know about the `character set` option that is supported by load data local infile. But, even though I don't get error when I put `CHARACTER SET latin1` in my query, I want everything to be UTF-8. And What happens if I another users uses a file that's neither in UTF-8 or latin1?

So how do I found out in which character set the user uploaded document is and how do I convert it to UTF-8?

Comment: That's theoretically impossible ;) Fortunately, there are some heuristics that can help you guess the correct encoding with a high probability. See e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824902/iconv-any-encoding-to-utf-8

Answer (score 1):

you can find the character encoding using mb_detect_encoding before running the $query. This will help you detect the most likely encoding before you load your file.

suppose the file name is in **$str**

here is a basic example that might help.

```
<?php
/* Detect character encoding with current detect_order */
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);

/* "auto" is expanded according to mbstring.language */
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, "auto");

/* Specify encoding_list character encoding by comma separated list */
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, "JIS, eucjp-win, sjis-win");

/* Use array to specify encoding_list  */
$ary[] = "ASCII";
$ary[] = "JIS";
$ary[] = "EUC-JP";
echo mb_detect_encoding($str, $ary);
?>
```

here is the link to php.net's [mb_detect_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

> This is just a work-around and a heuristic way. Make sure you handle
>   all the exceptions that might incure (*which might be tedious, i
>   guess*)

**There is a class written that might suite your requirement (*Haven't tested the code*) on [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8438-PHP-Detect-the-encoding-of-text-from-a-file-or-string.html#view_files)**

Comment: You should at least mention that this is only a heuristic, i.e. can go horribly wrong.

Comment: Yes @Deduplicator, you are right. should make an edit right away. Thanks!

Comment: @Guns Thank you very much for your answer. Really appreciate it. But I can't help thinking that I can't be the first person to stumble upon this. As you and 'Deduplicator' point out there's much more to it than this script. Isn't there an open-source class that's working quite well?

Comment: @DavidJanssen, modified the answer with a link. This might help you.